# Finding the Closest CLLocation

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation, currentlocation

How do I find the closest location from the user? Basically, I have a bunch of `CLLocation`'s, and I want to find the one closest to the user. I have retrieved the users current location but I want to find the closest `CLLocation`. How would I go about doing this? You can just `NSLog` the closest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CLLocation *currentLocation;
NSArray *otherLocations;

CLLocation *closestLocation;
CLLocationDistance closestDistance = DBL_MAX;

for (CLLocation* location in otherLocations) {
    CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
    if (distance < closestDistance) {
        closestLocation = location;
        closestDistance = distance;
    }
}
NSLog(@"the closest location is %@", closestLocation);
```

Comment: Need to update `closestDistance` when you update `closestLocation`